# Powershell stopped working

Tags: powershell

I get the following message  in my system 7, "powershell stopped working", very often.  I tried a system scan and everything is ok. What is causing this message?  How do I solve this?

Comment: Are you doing something to trigger it, or is it just popping up randomly regardless of what you're doing?  When you say you performed a "system scan", which scan did you perform exactly? Can you successfully open a plain PowerShell prompt?

Comment: define 'system scan'. do you mean sfc.exe as Logem has suggested?

Comment: I did a sfc.exe. It is popping up randomly.

Comment: Have you upgraded powershell from the default installed version (v2.0)?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
Go to the start menu, and type `cmd`, right-click, and click "Run As Administrator".Then type `sfc /scannow`, and press enter.

Comment: I already did and everything was OK.